# Does the Oberth effect motivate complementing ion electric propulsion with chemical rocketry?

Tags: gravity-assist, advanced-propulsion, solid-fuel, oberth-maneuver

The solar electric ion propulsion engine of the Dawn spacecraft to Vesta and Ceres used [Mars for gravity assist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawn_%28spacecraft%29#Cruise). Would it be gainful to complement an ion engine with a high thrust (solid) chemical rocket to fire only during such a gravity assist in order to make maximum use of the [Oberth effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oberth_effect)? Or can it be indicated that the burden of launching and carrying its mass would be difficult to make up for in that way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solid rocket motors **have** been used successfully to exploit the Oberth effect during the most critical phase of an interplanetary mission - target body orbit insertion. NASA's [Magellan mission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magellan_%28spacecraft%29#Attitude_control_and_propulsion) to Venus used a standard Thiokol/ATK [Star 48](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_48) propulsion module.

This same module was employed as an upper stage in the New Horizons flight to Pluto and beyond.

A mass-conscious mission designer is always aware of solids' low specific impulse, yet may use them for their reliability in single-burn maneuvers. Powered gravity assists are mostly done in several burns (Venus-Earth-Earth, for instance), and require very high precision as far as burn $\Delta V$ is concerned. It may be also desirable to re-program burn length in-flight, which is not possible with solids. Hypergolic-based thrusters are much more convenient, well-tested, and flexible.

To sum it up, a mission with an ion thruster **could** use a solid rocket motor for orbit insertion, if the approach velocity is simply too high for a low-thrust capture. Multiple powered gravity assists - not really. One should note that powered assists are much less desirable mass-wise than unpowered ones.